# How to unset a field in Mongoose with findByIdAndUpdate

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack, mean

I use MEAN stack. On my backend I use findByIdAndUpdate function in Mongoose to do the update operation in CRUD. I also use Bootstrap UI date picker. On "clearing" of the date, uib-datepicker-popup resets the scope value for the date field to undefined. Now I pass the scope resource object into Mongoose with a HTTP PUT angular $resource call, it won't pass the null properties in the json object. My date field is simply missing and unpopulated in the json object and PUTting out. Therefore The original date stays and I failed to reset the date field in the MongoDB document.

How should I approach deleting a certain field, then, as in unsetting with Mongoose built in "findByIdAndUpdate"?

Comment: Are you just essentially asking to "replace" the matched document with the content you are sending rather than update the the existing fields and leaving those not present in the document untouched. i.e Document stored is `{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }` and you send `{ a: 2, b: 3 }` and that is the document you want stored. Not `{ a: 2, b: 3, c: 3 }`, which is what you currently get. Is that it?

Comment: You're not answering but I presume from the context of your question that is in fact what you are asking. Mongoose has an option `"overwrite": true` which can be set on all "update" variants. All you need is supply the object to "replace" and include "overwrite" in the options, as is demonstrated on the duplicate.

Comment: I think you got me right. Sorry if the question wasn't clear. I looked into the other answer and it seems to solve my problem. I just have to give it a try when I have a chance. However, can you please let me know if there's any difference between `upsert` option and `overwrite`? They both seem to overwrite from the answer posted in the original/duplicate question.

Comment: No they do not do the same thing and the other answer posted there that is not mine is incorrect. An ["upsert"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) is a totally different thing and I do believe I clearly explain what the purpose of `overwrite` is, though it basically restores the "default" behavior of what the driver does from how mongoose alters it for "convenience".

Comment: Thanks a lot Neil, add the overwrite param now proven to work. Way to go solving my problem =)